# Android create xml with jackson-dataformat-xml

Tags: java, android, xml, json

i try to create a XML with a Libary "jackson-dataformal-xml" but i get allways a nullpointer. The data isnt empty.

This is the class i would like as a xml:

```
public class OrderData implements Serializable {

public ProductType productType;
public ContractData contractData;
public PersonalData personalData;
public SepaData sepaData;
}
```

This is how i try it:

```
public class DataToXml {


public String writeXML(OrderData data) {
    String xml = null;
    ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    try {
        xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(data);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xml;
    }
}
```

And here i would like to show it as a Toast:

```
    mButtonNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCurrentScreen < MAX_SCREEN_INDEX) {
                goToNextScreen();
            } else {
                dataToxml = new DataToXml(); // I forgot this:/
                **String xml = dataToXml.writeXML(mUserData);**//I get here a nullpointer.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), xml,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I get now a new Error:

03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750): java.lang.VerifyError: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlFactory
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.(XmlMapper.java:44)
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at 
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-12 17:07:40.347: E/AndroidRuntime(31750):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thx for every help.